# Why is DATEPART(weekday, GETDATE()) not working for Saturday?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an automatic process and I don't want it to run on Saturday and on Sunday. Since I'm able to decide for whom to start the process through a `WHERE` condition in Microsoft SQL Server, I thought about assigning this `WHERE` condition:

```
[...]
WHERE DATEPART(weekday, GETDATE()) <> 1 -- No Sunday
AND DATEPART(weekday, GETDATE()) <> 7 -- No Saturday
AND [other conditions]
```

Anyway, for some reason this process didn't start on Sunday, but it started on Saturday. What am I missing?

Comment: `DATEPART` is language dependant. What is the language setting of the `LOGIN` that is running the task? If I ran your SQL I would get no results on a Monday (`1`) and Sunday (`7`). Ideally, you should be using a language-agnostic method.

Comment: Rather than cryptic date numbers that depend on date first settings you might consider `FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'dddd', 'en-GB') NOT IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday')` (or an appropriate culture for your team)

Comment: Eh, `FORMAT` is proven to not be ideal for performance, @MartinSmith . I'd be interested to see if it is detrimental to such a clause in the `WHERE`.

Comment: Thank you @Larnu, the language is us_english

Comment: I would imagine a query "deciding for whom to start the process" is going to be dealing with a fairly minimal amount of rows where this is no concern and where readability trumps any performance concerns.

Comment: @MartinSmith, yep, the query is dealing with many rows. Anyway, yes, the `FORMAT` is certainly more readable

Comment: Datepart weekday is specifically dependant on @@DATEFIRST setting, which is not language but region dependant.

Comment: How many is "many"? And does this check have to go in a WHERE clause anyway rather than just an `IF <is_weekend> RETURN;`?

Comment: @siggemannen, that setting is *tied* to the `LOGIN`'s language setting; `LOGIN`s don't have a "region" setting. A `LOGIN` with their `LANGUAGE` set to `BRITISH` (as apaprently we don't speak English here in England) would have `DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE())` return `1` today. Someone who had it set to (American) `ENGLISH` would have `DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE())` return `2`.

Comment: @MartinSmith the rows are more or less 15k, and yes, the check has to be in a `WHERE` condition

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you on?

Comment: Oh right 15K is not "many" - I'd just go for whatever is most readable rather than worry about saving a few milliseconds of CPU time (or < 1ms even https://i.stack.imgur.com/boTrI.png)

Comment: @Larnu, fair enough, what i meant was that it's not dependent on SET LANGUAGE xyz; but rather on another setting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is documented in [`DATEPART`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#week-and-weekday-datepart-arguments)

> For a week (wk, ww) or weekday (dw) datepart, the DATEPART return
> value depends on the value set by SET DATEFIRST.

The default value for `DATEFIRST` is in turn derived from the language of the login. As you are apparently restricted to just changing the `WHERE` clause you presumably can't set that explicitly. You can change the default language of the login running the job or do some cryptic arithmetic with `@@DATEFIRST` to make it agnostic to that.

Or you could consider doing something like

```
WHERE FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'dddd', 'en-GB') NOT IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday')
```

`FORMAT` calls out to the CLR so does have some potential performance impact visible in micro benchmarks. Hopefully the expression will only be evaluated once though rather than re-evaluated for each row (potentially in a filter with a startup predicate).

And even in the worst case if it is evaluated 15K times this is likely to be no worse than an extra double digit ms of CPU time used by something that executes once a day (?) - I'm sure you will have much bigger performance fish to fry than that.